# Requisição assicrona para retornar a tabela atualizada

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estou a usar uma requisição assíncrona para retornar a tabela actualizada e substituir a anterior, mas estou com problemas ao mostrar os dados.

Código com a minha tabela:

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display: none;">
<table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_table"> 
<h1 style="font-size: 30px"><strong>Saída de Luvas</strong></h1>
<thead>  
<tr> 
<th>Colaborador</th>
<th>Tipo Luva</th>
<th>Tamanho</th>
<th>Estado</th>
<th>Ação</th>   
<th>Eliminar</th>                               
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php  do{ ?>  
<td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto["Tipo"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto["Tamanho"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Estado"]; ?></td>
td><button type="button" name="edit" id="<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-dander btn-sm delete" onclick="remove(this)"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
</tr>  
<?php } while($produto = $result->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</tbody>      
</table>   
</div>
```

Js:

```
function inserir_registo()
{  

    var dadosajax = {
        'Id' : $("#Id").val(),
        'TipoLuvas' : $("#TipoLuvas").val(),
        'Tamanho' : $("#Tamanho").val(),
        'Quantidade' : $("#Quantidade").val(),
        'Observacao1' : $("#Observacao1").val(),
        'Estado' : $("#Estado").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: './atribuicaoluvas',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
         (function ($) {$(document).ready(function () {
          $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');
         });       
         })(jQuery);  
        $.ajax({
             //link o arquivo php que fará a consulta para atualizar a tabela
             url: './atualizarluvas',
             type: 'get',
             success: function(data){
                 $("#employee_table").empty();
                 $("#employee_table").append(data);
              }
          });
      }     
   });
}
```

O arquivo `atualizarluvas` é o que utilizo para atualizar a tabela:

```
$query = "SELECT raddb.RequisicaoLuvas.Id, nome, Tipo, raddb.TamanhoLuvas.Tamanho, Quantidade, Observacao, DataRequis, raddb.Status.Estado 

FROM raddb.RequisicaoLuvas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoLuvas

ON raddb.TipoLuvas.Id = raddb.RequisicaoLuvas.TipoLuvas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TamanhoLuvas

ON raddb.TamanhoLuvas.Id = raddb.RequisicaoLuvas.Tamanho LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.usuarios

ON raddb.usuarios.id = raddb.RequisicaoLuvas.Colaborador LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.Status

ON raddb.Status.Id = raddb.RequisicaoLuvas.Estado WHERE raddb.Status.Estado = 'Pendente'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      echo json_encode($row);
```

Mas quando faço editar e gravo, mostra assim a tabela atualizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas devia mostrar o resultado da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No `success` do seu ajax vc precisa montar a tabela, vc está apenas jogando o json no seu html. Você pode mandar a tabela montada no `php` ou montar no seu success do ajax.

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil após fechar a modal dar um refresh na página. Aí a tabela já virá atualizada.

Comment: @Sam se atualizar a página a tabela desaparece e tenho de clicar no botão novamente para mostrar a mesma e pretendo que atualize a tabela sem fechar a mesma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa montar a linha da tabela e inserir no `tbody`. Do jeito que está fazendo, você apenas está inserindo o retorno do JSON em forma de string na tabela toda.

O seletor está incorreto. Em vez de `$("#employee_table")` deveria ser `$("#employee_table tbody")`, porque o alvo é o `tbody`.

Use `dataType: "json",` no AJAX para que o retorno seja em forma de objeto JSON e não uma string JSON.

No `success` você pode construir uma linha usando [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), pegando os valores do JSON retornado:

```
var linha = `<tr>
<td>${ data.nome }</td> 
<td>${ data.Tipo }</td> 
<td>${ data.Tamanho }</td>
<td>${ data.Estado }</td>
<td><button type="button" name="edit" id="${ data.Id }" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit_data" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="${ data.Id }" class="btn btn-dander btn-sm delete" onclick="remove(this)"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
</tr>`;
$("#employee_table tbody").html(linha);
```

Comment: mas neste caso eu não vou mostrar mais uma linha, ao alterar o estado de pendente para entregue, a linha vai é deixar de aparecer na tabela

Comment: Alterei a resposta.

Comment: está a retornar assim, [Tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka7q1.png)

Comment: Deve ter feito alguma coisa errado. Mostra um print do código.

Comment: print do código [Código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nadXi.png)

Comment: O valor da variável `linha` deve estar entre o símbolo ` (crase) e não aspas simples como colocou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98192/discussion-between-bruno-and-sam).

Comment: surgiu um problema com as requisições assíncronas, posso só tirar uma dúvida contigo no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99949/room-for-iniciante-and-sam)?